# Accessing files locally on cloud notebook

Tags: python, r, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, cloud

I am relatively new to Cloud Notebooks. I am currently working on a Machine Learning Project. I'll be working with extremely heavy datasets so I decided to use the Google Cloud Platform to run the notebooks (Jupyter Lab). My question is how can I access some of the excel sheets which are stored on our company's local drive without having to upload them on google drive or other places. The files can not be uploaded as they are highly restricted and proprietary. I will be using python 80% of the times and R 20% of the times.

Thanks!

Comment: I think one solution may be to have an internal server and access the data through that server but I'm not sure it will make a lot of sense since it would require a lot of bandwidth and, still, to process the data on google cloud you need to import it (therefore it will be in the server in some sense). Why not making a contract with google of microsoft for a reserved space? I think they will host your data without having to look it in that case

Comment: We do have our own shared network drive. Is it possible that I can access those files in cloud notebook through that network drive?

Comment: I don't know since I'm not an expert on that, I think you'll have to open ports and communicate through them. I still think that if you buy an account on any cloud platform your data cannot be accessed by the company hosting however, so I would still suggest you the easy way to make an account and upload the data there

Comment: I am also struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: It doesn't work if I am trying to access the excel sheets stored on the local drive from google cloud notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to use Cloud VPN to create an [HA VPN gateway to a Peer VPN gateway](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn). With this solution, you will connect the Jupyter Notebook that is in the GCP cloud network to your computer, where your local files are, and this connection is through an encrypted tunnel(VPN). You will connect to this VPN if you want to read the files, and you can disconnect after you are done with that.

You can see more documentation about this [product](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=latam-MX-all-es-dr-BKWS-all-all-trial-e-dr-1011454-LUAC0016076&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_542579078128-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20BKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20Networking_VPN-KWID_43700066058826817-kwd-1411571900574&utm_term=KW_vpn%20gcp-ST_VPN%20GCP&gclid=CjwKCAiA6Y2QBhAtEiwAGHybPSxP6oleLa-Xq97bjqjtRSL5Zq0VjngJN9yNteGWmE9iYWDMMGhfyxoC1NIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

After implementing this solution and connecting to the VPN, you can execute your code and access the Excel sheets which are stored in your company's local drive.

You can see this example; with this code, you could read your Excel file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')
print (df)
```

You can see this document about the function [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#).